# bash filter the file names by regex or similar in a while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, filenames, filter

Currently I have the following bash script that gets the width and height of all the files in the directory:

```
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do 
  width=$(identify -format "%w" "$f")
  height=$(identify -format "%h" "$f")
  echo "$width , $height"
done
```

How can I only get the height/width of files where the filename ends in `-example99.jpg`?

Comment: This seems like a variant of [Bash Pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Just use `for f in ...`

Comment: If you aren’t doing anything besides displaying the values, then there are easier options. If you want to do something different with the dimensions, you’ll get better answers by saying so.

Comment: @JeffSchaller please see the updated question

Comment: At this point, you should probably open a new question, since this has multiple answers (and has been accepted). Your initial question was (unintentionally) misleading, causing the two other answerers to come up with solutions that replicated your results, when you really wanted something else. In your new question, give enough of the "whole picture" to get answers that really answer your problem.

Comment: @JeffSchaller please see the question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410243/bash-rename-files-in-directory-useing-regex here i added a new one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for filename in *-example99.jpg
do
  width=$(identify -format "%w" "$filename")
  height=$(identify -format "%h" "$filename")
done
```

Comment: as you mentioned in your comment, yes, i'd like to do more with it, namely, I want to rename that file to another, please see the updated question for the details.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a loop here, just:

```
identify -format "%w , %h\n" ./*-example99.jpg
```

(add `%f` to the format if you also want the file name).

To avoid running 2 `identify` commands per file, you can also do (here using `ksh93` or `bash` syntax):

```bash
unset -v file width height
file=(./*-example99.jpg)
eval "$(identify -format 'width+=(%w) height+=(%h)\n' "${file[@]}")"

for ((i = 0; i < ${#file[@]}; i++)); do
  printf 'File: %s (%s x %s)\n' "${file[i]}" "${width[i]}" "${height[i]}"
done
```

(or `for i in "${!file[@]}"; do...` to loop over the keys of the `$file` array).

That assumes `identify` can identify the width and height for all the files, and you wouldn't use that approach for file types that can contain several images (like animated `gif`s).

Answer (score 1):

Simple **`find`** + **`identify`** approach:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*-example99.jpg" -exec identify -format "%w, %h\n" {} \;
```

Example output:

```
640, 480
```