# bash rename files in directory using regex

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

Currently I have the following bash script that does a for loop in the directory:

```
for filename in *-example99.jpg
do
   width=$(identify -format "%w" "$filename")
   myVar="newName$width"
   new=$(echo $filename | sed -e 's/\.jpg$/"$myVar".jpg/')
   echo "$filename" "$new"
   mv "$filename" "$new"
done
```

actually, I want to rename the file from:

`myfilename-example99.jpg`

to:

`myfilename-newName.jpg`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=batch+rename or the list of questions on the right side bar

Comment: Your previous question investigated the image dimensions; is that no longer involved?

Comment: Note that “newName” is a static string; you’d be renaming all the files to one...

Comment: @JeffSchaller i will be getting some part of the custom variable from the width of the image.

Comment: Apart from [the quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) being off (esp. with the `sed`), doesn't the renaming and the loop look fine?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call out to sed: bash parameter substitution can handle this task. Try this:

```
suffix="-example99.jpg"
for filename in *"$suffix"        # wildcard * must remain unquoted
do
   width=$(identify -format "%w" "$filename")
   new="${filename%$suffix}-newName${width}.jpg"
   echo mv "$filename" "$new"
done
```

The `${filename%$suffix}` removes the suffix from the end of the string. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 0):

Simply with **`prename`** (*Perl* `rename`):

```
myVar="newName"
prename 's/-[^-.]+(\.jpg)$/-'"$myVar"'$1/' *-example99.jpg
```

Comment: how can i specifiy the file that is being looped? cuz i am inside a for loop